# Получение имен имеющихся баз данных. MSSQL

Tags: c#, база-данных, sql-server, winforms

Есть Базы Данных на MSSQL. Надо создать класс на C# который получает имена и id БД. Записать их в массив, и после этого вывести этот массив в `Listbox`. Когда пользователь выбирает нужную БД (`listBox_SelectedIndexChanged`) открывается другая форма и загружаются все таблицы выбранной БД.

*Как это реализовать?*

Comment: Если Вы спрашиваете, каким запросом можно получить список баз данных, то это `SELECT name, database_id FROM sys.databases`.

Comment: спасибо! а как это присвоить на массив и вывести из массива на listbox? а это можно сделать?

Comment: Отмечать свой вопрос как "часто задаваемый" - тут надо большое самомнение...

Comment: Все можно реализовать. Что именно не получается?

Answer (score 1):

Реализация следующая:

1. Подключаешься
2. Отправляешь запрос на выбор имеющихся баз данных
3. Результат запроса записываешь в массив
4. Заполняешь listbox данными из массива

При выборе в listbox:

1. Подключаешься уже к конкретной базе
2. Выбираешь имена всех имеющихся в ней таблиц
3. Отображаешь полученный список на новой форме.

*Что получилось, а что нет?* Все получилось - **молодец - ты справился**.